# Intersect float rows in two numpy matrices with precision

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, intersection

I'm looking for rows in B which are close to any of the rows in A

example:
eps = 0.1

A = [[1.22, 1.33], [1.45, 1.66]]

B = [[1.25, 1.34], [1.77, 1.66], [1.44, 1.67]]

Result: [[1.22, 1.33], [1.45, 1.66]]

Comment: Not sure I follow, but it looks like your result is returning the lowest value per column, which also just happens to be `A[0]`.

Comment: no, just all values from A[0] is near B[0] ( abs(A[0][i] - B[0][i])  < eps), i need to find all rows with this rule, but A and B - numpy matrices, so iterative N^2 solution is not my variant.

Comment: So what value do you want in a cell if there are no values within eps? 0?

Comment: Are you trying to do this: `A[(abs(A-B) < eps).all(axis = 1)]`?

Comment: @ProfessorPantsless, thank you! That's exactly what i was looking for. Maybe you know solution, if we have different number of rows in our matrices?

Comment: @ProfessorPantsless, maybe you know solution, if we have different number of rows in our matrices? For example 
A = [[1.22, 1.33], [1.45, 1.66]]

B = [[1.25, 1.34], [1.77, 1.66], [1.44, 1.67]]

Result: [[1.22, 1.33], [1.45, 1.66]]

Comment: Are you looking for rows in `B` which are close to any of the rows in `A`? Please edit your question to better illustrate the logic to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to filter to elements in `A` which are close to **any** element in `B`, you can use `broadcast` and `tile` to do an exhaustive check:

```
import numpy as np

eps = .1
A = np.array([[1.22, 1.33], [1.45, 1.66]])
B = np.array([[1.25, 1.34], [1.77, 1.66], [1.44, 1.67]])


# broadcast A based on the shape of B
A_ext = np.broadcast_to(A, (B.shape[0],) + A.shape)

# tile B and reshape, this will allow comparison of all elements in A to all elements in B
B_ext = np.tile(B, A.shape[0]).reshape(A_ext.shape)

# create the boolean array
A_bool = np.abs(A_ext - B_ext) < eps

# reduce array to match number of elements in A
# .all() will result in an array representing which elements in A are close to each element in B
# .any() represents if A is close to any of the elements in B
A_mask = A_bool.all(axis = -1).any(axis = 0)

# final result
A[A_mask]
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Professor Pantsless' [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72219834/intersect-float-rows-in-two-numpy-matrices-with-precision?noredirect=1#comment127599632_72219834) and would expand on it's use here:

Your arrays look like so:

```
# array A
1.22 1.33
1.45 1.66

# array B
1.25 1.34
1.77 1.66
```

Your desired result (per your OP) matches to `A[0]`, or `1.22 1.33`. This indicates that you wish to return an array of the rows inside array `A` in which all elements in a row are `< eps` when compared to the same indexed row of array 'B':

```
# array C
np.abs(A[0] - B[0]) # --> True  True
np.abs(A[1] - B[1]) # --> False True
```

This is achievable with a [boolean index](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) achieved using:

```
>>> A[(np.abs(A-B) < eps).all(axis = 1)]
```

Breaking down this line:

```
>>> np.abs(A-B)
0.03 0.01
0.32 0.00
>>> np.abs(A-B) < eps
True  True
False True
# notice this matches the comments above
>>> (np.abs(A-B) < eps).all(axis = 1)
True False
```

The `(np.abs(A-B) < eps)` returns a new array of booleans, and the `.all(axis = 1)` checks along the first axis (so column wise) of each row to see if all elements per row are `True`. Since the first row of array `C` is all `True`, it returns `True`; this does not hold for the second row as its `False True` so it returns `False`. What you're left with is an array of shape `(N, )`.

So now the final breakdown is:

```
>>> A[(np.abs(A-B) < eps).all(axis = 1)]
1.22 .133
# since this is access A like A[(True, False)]
```

w.r.t. your latest [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72219834/intersect-float-rows-in-two-numpy-matrices-with-precision/72231242#comment127608335_72219834), you cannot do that because of NumPy's [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) rules. These rules are pretty similar to standard [matrix multiplication](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/x9e81a4f98389efdf:matrices/x9e81a4f98389efdf:properties-of-matrix-multiplication/a/matrix-multiplication-dimensions) rules. So you cannot take a `2x2` matrix and multiply by a `3x2` because the inner dimensions don't work.